# Is the in-code representation of multibyte numbers always big endian?

Tags: endianness

Big and Little Endians represent the way we store bytes of multibyte numbers (int16, int32, etc.) in memory, transfer over the network, serialize, and so on.

I know how they work, what they represent and what problems we can face if we don't understand them. For example, one problem could be if we use a library that works with little endian, but we pass to it big endian serialized file.

What I'm curious about is whether the in-code is always a Big-endian representation?

**What I mean by this is that regardless of whether the underlying machine uses Little or Big endian for executing program or saving into memory, in-code multibyte numbers are always represented in Big endian form and we work in that manner with these numbers.**

---

What I mean by saying "*in-code*"? The following:

If the machine (PC/laptop) uses Little endian, it stores the number `-9` as  "0b00001001 00000000 00000000 **1**0000000" (sign bit is bolded) in memory. However, when I write a code (for example in C) on that machine, set `int a = -9` and print it as bits or work with its bits it is always represented/considered  as "0b**1**0000000 00000000 00000000 00001001" (sign bit is bolded), so always in Big endian manner even though the machine is Little endian and we would expect it to be as "0b00001001 00000000 00000000 **1**0000000" also in code (such as in memory).

---

Two examples of what I mean (in both examples, the underlying machine is assumed to work with little-endian):

1. number `-9` represented in binary manner in-code always looks like "0b**1**0000000 00000000 00000000 00001001" although on machine it is in memory actually stored as "0b00001001 00000000 00000000 **1**0000000" (with bold I denoted sign bit).
2. `1<<X` represents shifting right most bit (least significant bit) by number of X

   - which means that in case `X = 31` we are setting most significant bit for int32 (it is consistent with the big-endian representation)
   - if the in-code is Little endian, to set the most significant bit we would have to use `1<<7` (which I almost never see)

Therefore, is the in-code representation actually always Big-Endian. In the programming languages I have worked with so far (C, C++, GO), the in-code representation of multi-byte numbers has always been in Big-Endian. What is your opinion, have you encountered other cases?

Also, Andrew Chow (one of the main Bitcoin developers) wrote the following [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/120300/145749) (it matches my experience so far):

> When you write code, it's always big endian even though the actual representation in memory may be little endian.

Comment: What _precisely_ do you mean by "in-code representation"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I bolded my meaning of "in-code" plus I gave two example.

Comment: Your description is not clear to me (and other users) - could you please try a different explanation rather than just saying "read what I already wrote"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I edited question to make it clearer. I hope its fine now.

Comment: Are you basically asking "are there any languages where numbers in source code written with the least significant digit first?" e.g. "one thousand two hundred and thirty four" is written `4321` rather than `1234`. If so, that doesn't really have anything to do with multi-byte endianness as it applies as much for "twelve" being written `12` rather than `21`.

Comment: @PhilipKendall No, I wrote another question. I hope I explained it better https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448880/my-computer-is-little-endian-but-when-i-wrote-code-it-always-represent-them-as

Comment: How can a machine "use" little or big endian... it feels like there is a misunderstanding of what "endian-ness" means...

Comment: Or are you interpreting "in-code" as characters in a text file? Or code as in the character code from, for example, UTF-16?

Comment: @GregBurghardt "Machine uses endian" in context how it stores a multibyte numbers (for example int32). For example, if machine uses Little endian then the less significant byte goes on the smallest address and so on. However, regardless of which endian some machine uses, in-code multi-bytes are always represented in Big endian manner. By saying in-code I refer on execution of the code. E.g. `int a = 9` will be represented (when print, doing bin operation etc.) as "0b00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001" even thought machine is Little endian and we expect "0b00001001 00000000 00000000 00000000"

Comment: @GregBurghardt I do not see anything strange in this question, but hey all hate me and downvoted my question for some reason...

Comment: I used to tutor this and dealt with different endian concepts in specifications and code. I can see a good answer to write here. It starts by explaining why the answer is no.

Comment: @candied_orange It would be nice to see a nice detailed answer to this topic. With the programming languages I encountered, it was always like this as I wrote, so I wanted to see if there were other cases (but they all hated me and downvoted for some reason). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're confusing a **storage representation** with a **display representation**.  Numbers are stored using the endianness specified by the underlying platform.  The *display* of a number is not concerned with endianness at all.

Comment: I just feel the need to point out that -9 is `0b10000000 00001001` only in sign-magnitude representation, which is practically non-existent for integers.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes, the actual representation (and in-memory store) will be in 2's complements. However, it was easier for me to put it in "sign-magnitude" form to illustrate the "problem". Anyway, thanks for the note :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about numeric literals in source code?  Numeric literals (whether decimal, hexadecimal, binary) are always written in big-endian notation in source code. E.g. the number:

```
int x = 256;
```

Represent the same number, regardless of the endianness of the underlying architecture. But the sequence of bytes stored in memory might be `01 00` or `00 01` depending on architecture (assuming a 16-bit int for simplicity).

In hexadecimal the same number is written as:

```
int x = 0x0100;
```

And again it can be represented in memory as the bytes `01 00` or `00 01`

Bit shift operations can be visualized as if all the bits in the word were arranged in a big-endian sequence. The endianness of a platform does not affect the semantics of the bit shift operators.

In general, you don't have to worry about endianness when operating on integers. It only becomes an issue when you convert between integers and byte arrays.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was referring to, that is, no matter of the endian of my machine, I always write code and think as it is Big Endian. So any kind of bitwise operation, prints, declaring variables and so on, we are doing in Big endian manner, even when it is underlying Little endian.  And only issue is when we are representing "multibyte" numbers as array of bytes since then the first byte (on smallest address) won't be the most significant as it would be in Big endian, but the least significant one.

Comment: Actually I knew all this. But I only asked the question to check and see if there are programming languages in which we have to take "machine endians" into account.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the in-code representation of multibyte numbers always big endian?

No.

It's not.

As proof look at your own question. You laid out how you wanted bits organized very clearly. And that layout could easily be made into part of a programming language. One that had a convention that said how to interpret those bits as a number. Thus you could write little endian code on big endian hardware. Why would anyone do that? To teach people that absolutes like "always" can make questions trivial to answer.

What I suspect you really mean to ask is if you can trust code not create it's own endian issues, completely removed from Intel's little curse on computer science. As I've demonstrated a malicious esoteric language can violate that trust. But most languages carefully avoid expressing how bits should be laid out in code even while enabling bit by bit manipulation. They try to abstract that issue away from you so you don't have to think about it.

But abstractions often leak.

> ```c
> int main()
> {
>  int x = 1;
>
>  char *y = (char*)&x;
>
>  printf("%c\n",*y+48);
> }
> ```
>
> [stackoverflow.com - C program to check little vs. big endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791864/c-program-to-check-little-vs-big-endian)

If c perfectly abstracted endian issues away from you this little test for endianness couldn't be written. No a perfect abstraction isn't what they've given you.

What they gave you was a way to take a string of numeric characters and encode them as a number on whatever hardware regardless of it's endianness. That abstraction holds up so long as you keep thinking of those bits as one number. Soon as you start thinking of them as a bunch of little numbers the abstraction falls apart.

But, at least in c (and many other languages), even when that number requires multiple bytes, the way the characters are laid out in code could be described as big endian.

The number you've been throwing around looks like 8000 0009 in hex. At least it does when [MSb and MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) are presented on the left. Put either one on the right and you have the classic byte order little endian. Put them both on the right and you have an argument brewing because, yes, some people swear that's little endian as well. Networking people aren't those people because they don't believe left and right exist. They believe in first and last. Which drives specification writers nuts because paper has very definite opinions about left and right.

What endian means depends on context.

One thing to keep in mind is a string of bits in a chip can't tell where you're standing when you look at it. Bits laid out on paper can. That difference right there causes a fair bit of trouble.

> What I mean by this is that regardless of whether the underlying machine uses Little or Big endian for executing program or saving into memory, in-code multibyte numbers are always represented in Big endian form and we work in that manner with these numbers.

I'll say it again. No.

The reason why is because regardless of the underlying machine, the language is using a convention to figure out what you mean when you type numbers. That convention is determined by the language creator. It is not imposed by anything other than the occasional merciful common sense. Much as we all may wish this had to be big endian no amount of convention hotel trips or RFCs will stop that one crazy programmer from writing a language where a number is expressed with its most significant [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) on the right and it's most significant byte on the left.

Now that said, in most languages, big endian is what I expect in source code.  At least until the language spec breaks my heart.

Answer (score 2):

"Big-endian" and "little-endian" are terms for **describing the order of bytes in a multi-byte value**. They are necessary because this order can be either of two possibilities.

What you are talking about would be the order of bits in a byte, which is always the same by definition, so I would find it misleading if someone called that "big-endian".

Comment: I know they are the terms of bytes. Please take a look at my 2 examples.

Comment: This is incorrect the order of bits can be relevant when data is transmitted over a serial link (network, serial cable etc) in such cases big and little endian are appropriate terms to describe which bit goes first over the link.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be missing is that endianness is only relevant when you are dealing with parts of a computer that are byte oriented.

The processor doesn't deal with multi-byte representations. The registers that a processor uses are typically 32 to 64 bits wide in modern processors and operations that operate on values that are wider than a register are rare.

And when a value gets printed by a program, the printing logic ensures that an easily recognizable positional representation is used, which happens to coincide with a big-endian byte order.